# Python: Comparing Lists

Tags: python, list

I have come across a small problem. Say I have two lists:

```
list_A = ['0','1','2']
list_B = ['2','0','1']
```

I then have a list of lists:

```
matrix = [
['56','23','4'],
['45','5','67'],
['1','52','22']
]
```

I then need to iterate through list_A and list_B and effectively use them as co-ordinates. For example I take the firs number from list A and B which would be '0' and '2', I then use them as co-ordinates: `print matrix[0][2]`

I then need to do the same for the 2nd number in list A and B and the 3rd number in list A and B and so forth for however long List A and B how would be. How do this in a loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
matrix = [
['56','23','4'],
['45','5','67'],
['1','52','22']
]

list_A = ['0','1','2']
list_B = ['2','0','1']

for x in zip(list_A,list_B):
    a,b=map(int,x)
    print(matrix[a][b])
# 4
# 45
# 52
```

Comment: Solved my TypeError problem too :)

Answer (score 2):

```
[matrix[int(a)][int(b)] for (a,b) in zip(list_A, list_B)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'zip' function could be of some use here. It will generate a list of pairs from list_A and list_B.

```
for (x,y) in zip(list_A, list_B):
    # do something with the coordinates
```